# Custom Display in Google Home Hub

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

i want to know Google Home Hub or Hub Nest display can be custom be like this pic? How can do that ?[image]

Help Me, Pls
Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the look and feel of your action for Google Home Hub and Nest hub using [Interactive Canvas](https://developers.google.com/assistant/interactivecanvas). With Interactive Canvas you show a webpage that can handle user input from the Google Assistant devices and changes depending on the input on Google Assistant devices with screens.

Sadly, Google only allows Interactive Canvas actions which are game experiences to go live at this moment. If this is something you don't want to make public, you can still use it, or you can wait until Google allows more actions than just gaming experiences.